# How to avoid that extra Enter input

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, clipboard

I want to put a command result to my clipboard.Such as my command is `echo I love you.`.Then I execute this in my `CMD`:

```
echo I love you.|clip
```

But actually I will get

> I love you.[Enter]

A extra CR character in my clipboard.How to avoid this?Furthermore,can I assign the string "I love you." to a variable `a`?As I try:

```
echo I love you.|set a=
```

will fail to do it.

Maybe I should post two question.But this two question very similar.Any body can help me?I'm in windows 10 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDit**
Use the set /p prompt to output text without appending cr/lf like echo always does. So:

```
set /P =I love you<Nul|clip
```

won't append the cr/lf

---

Capture/parse output of a command

Suppose you want to get hostname from this ping output:

```
> ping -4 -n 1 -a 127.0.0.1

Pinging Matar [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

This batch

```
For /f "tokens=2delims=[ " %%A in (
  'ping -n 1 -a 127.0.0.1^|find "["'
) do Echo %%A
```

Will return

```
Matar
```

---

This batch will store all non empty output lines to a pseudo array var and list the vars

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Cnt=100
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Ping -4 -n 1 -a 127.0.0.1') Do (
  Set /A Cnt+=1
  Set a[!Cnt:~-2!]=%%A
)
Set a[
```

Output

```
a[01]=Ping wird ausgeführt für Matar [127.0.0.1] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
a[02]=Antwort von 127.0.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
a[03]=Ping-Statistik für 127.0.0.1:
a[04]=    Pakete: Gesendet = 1, Empfangen = 1, Verloren = 0
a[05]=    (0% Verlust),
a[06]=Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
a[07]=    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Mittelwert = 0ms
```

Comment: Actually I know this,but the expression is very complex,I just use the `echo **` to simulate my question.

Comment: I mean you cannot do the first step `set love=mycommand` :)

Comment: Not that easy as in Linux/Unix. Cmd.exe doesn't handle multiline vars. You have to use `for /f` to parse the output of one command and process it.

Comment: Oh,Would you mind to give a example for that?I'm a newbie for cmd.exe.And How about my second question?Can we use "|" to assign a variable?

Comment: @yode I did append a sample, If asked for I'll explain in detail.

Comment: Sorry,I'm in bed,I will response you when I wake  in next morning. :)

Comment: Acutuall I want assign all output to variable `a` not just that hostname

Comment: Cmd.exe **CAN'T HANDLE MULTILINE VARS**. I showed a way to circumvent that. If you insist on being that var a, I change the second batch, but in everycase you'll have the numbers attached. Well I think both of your questions are answered as best is possible. Decent hint:  [someone-answers](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)